# Remove, mix, and take in: Cryptic Clues

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues, letters

> Here's another cryptic game to play.  The rules are as follows:
>
> - **A)** Nine of the 27 clues are standard cryptic clues
> - **B)** Nine clues are missing a word which is an answer from part A
> - **C)** Nine clues are missing a word which is an answer from part B
>
> Thus, the result will be nine 'chains' of three answers.
>   Finally, one of the answers from C will not be like the others.  Plug that answer into the clue in the title to get the final answer!

Example:

> - Never finished about a hook (5)
> - Happiness is a broken toenail (7)
> - I lost returning what dead men tell (2-4)

Would form a chain like this:

> - Happiness is a broken toenail  == **ELATION**
>  - *Elation* I lost returning what dead men tell == **NO-TALE**
>  - Never finished *no-tale* about a hook == **TALON**

*Note: The missing words will ALWAYS be part of the wordplay as in the example*

---

- Bloody ridiculous, nauseating; not extremely abhorrent  (8)
- Humiliation without a bottom  (8)
- Peculiar to give titles (5)
- A man is without a man (4)
- Without a good start, becomes trash (6)
- Psycho in a cult!  (7)
- Bodiless entity lurks inside... or titles PG horror! (11)
- Insurgents, grenades exploding, take Estonian capital (9)
- Nearly turns to anger  (3)
- One is without a heart  (4)
- Stationed all over to find cures (9)
- Dark and dashing loses cool briefly  (5)
- Country at sea with no poles. (6)
- Novel with no poles has little sparkles  (7)
- To lose nothing twice after two times cheating. (7)
- Kind of with no way to search   (3)
- Kind of cut European Union growth (4)
- Having no charge, lying around for days (5)
- Prepared without time for calmness  (8)
- Yank camera in, perhaps? (8)
- Without notice, reverses course  (7)
- Averages losing bet from characters (5)
- To take back some ancestral data? (4)
- Auto-iron has a water container (6)
- Diner eliminates tailless rodent (4)
- Has distribution with fine, popular drug  (8)
- Spying for the British: John Rex (7)

Comment: Are you sure the "bodiless ..." clue is correct? (It seems dicey in a way not easily explained by the A-B-C trickery; but I could easily be missing something.)

Comment: (actually, the more I look at it the more I suspect it _is_ explicable by the A-B-C trickery, though I haven't yet worked out exactly how)

Comment: You've singled out the most... um... Interesting clue. I think it's fair, but there is a lot going on. I'm not against a hint on that one if you're stuck for a bit.

Comment: Oh, the problem isn't that I don't know the answer to it -- I'm very confident I do. It's just that _either_ it's an A clue in which case it seems a bit dicey, _or_ it's a B or C clue and it's a little hard to see what insertion could make it work. My money's on the latter. (Current status: 8A, 5B, 2C; a couple of them are dubious.)

Comment: Actually, there is one clue I'd like a little confirmation on. Is the definition of "To take back ..." rather loose and even arguably _exactly the opposite of correct_?

Comment: (And I don't suppose "A man is without a man" is meant to say "A woman is without a man"? That would work quite nicely and provide a useful antecedent for another clue. But I expect it all works quite differently.)

Comment: Is "Yank..." meant to be (8) not (7)?

Comment: @Gareth: I'll respond to your answers and questions in a bit! Sorry for the delay and thanks for trying my puzzle!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solutions to clues**

I've grouped these into ABC sets. Carets indicate where the previous answer needs inserting. (In some cases there's more than one possible place; I picked the one that seems to me to make the best clue.)

> ```
> SANGUINE      Bloody ridiculous, nauseating; not extremely abhorrent (8)  A
> GUINEA        Country ^^^ at sea with no poles. (6)                       B
> GAIN          Kind of ^^^ cut European Union growth (4)                   C
>
> BASEMENT      Humiliation without a bottom (8)                            A
> MEANS         Averages losing bet from ^^^ characters (5)                 B
> NAMES         Peculiar ^^^ to give titles (5)                             C
>
> ANTIDOTES     Stationed all over to find cures (9)                        A
> SEDATION      ^^^ Prepared without time for calmness (8)                  B
> DATES         Having no charge, ^^^ lying around for days (5)             C
>
> CARAFE        Auto-iron has a water container (6)                         A
> CAFE          Diner ^^^ eliminates tailless rodent (4)                    B
> CAFFEINE      Has ^^^ distribution with fine, popular drug (8)            C
>
> POLTERGEIST   Bodiless entity lurks inside... or titles PG horror! (11)   A
> GLITTER       Novel ^^^ with no poles has little sparkles (7)             B
> LITTER        Without a good start, ^^^ becomes trash (6)                 C
>
> LOOKING       Spying for the British: John Rex (7)                        A
> BILKING       ^^^ To lose nothing twice after two times cheating. (7)     B
> ILK           Kind of ^^^ with no way to search (3)                       C
>
> AMERICAN      Yank camera in, perhaps? (7)                                A (8) not (7)
> ERIC          A man is ^^^ without a man (4)                              B
> IRE           ^^^ Nearly turns to anger (3)                               C
>
> RENEGADES     Insurgents, grenades exploding, take Estonian capital (9)   A
> RENEGES       Without notice, ^^^ reverses course (7)                     B
> GENE          ^^^ To take back some ancestral data? (4)                   C
>
> LUNATIC       Psycho in a cult! (7)                                       A
> UNLIT         Dark and dashing ^^^ loses cool briefly (5)                 B
> UNIT          One is ^^^ without a heart (4)                              C
> ```

The C-words are:

> NAMES LITTER DATES CAFFEINE ILK GAIN IRE GENE UNIT

Of these

> there isn't an odd one out if you look at *just the answers* but there is if you look at their genealogies: CAFFEINE is the only one where the A->B->C chain ever *adds* any letters.

The title

> then becomes Remove, mix CAFFEINE and take in (6) whose solution is EFFACE (def: remove; CAFFEINE*-IN).

Credit where due:

> SirDerpy found GENE, UNLIT and UNIT. athin and jafe figured out, respectively, which answer was special and what the answer was. (In my defence I will say that I failed to find those *before* OP gave some hints and they found them *after* :-).) Thanks to all; reader, if you like this answer then you might find something of theirs and upvote it.

Comment: All are correct so far except for 'NULL' which is not one of the answers.  You are absolutely right that Yank should be (8), and I apologize for that.  Great job solving it anyway.  For Bodiless Entity, the wordplay I was thinking was first word acting on the second to give 'E'.  And yes, that's doing double duty as the definition (along with the title of a PG horror movie) for sort of a double def &lit, which I know is stretching it a bit. This is similar to your concern with Psycho, so I think my &lit clue game might be a little off.  Oh, and 'take back' is a pretty straightforward indicator

Comment: I'm glad NULL was wrong :-). I'd been assuming "take back" was the obvious thing and am unsurprised to find I'm right about that even though my actual solution was wrong. And yeah, with an &lit the idea is that the _whole_ clue is def and the _whole_ clue is wordplay; you aren't supposed to just share parts of the clue between the two.

Comment: RENEGADES -> RENEGES becomes "GENE", paired with "To take back some ancestral data?"

LUNATIC becomes "UNLIT" ("Dark and dashing loses cool briefly" - also a questionable clue, as I don't see where "dashing" comes in), which becomes UNIT ("One is without a heart").

Comment: Nice! I think "dashing" is an anagram indicator.

Comment: Looks great!  You got it all!  For the final answer, I added a small hint in the title, and I suggest you compare Cs to the Bs they came from

Comment: I think the one word which is different is ROT13(PNSSRVAR) because ROT13(nyy punvaf ner 3 jbeqf jurer gur yrggref sebz n jbeq ner fhofrg bs vgf cerivbhf jbeq'f).

Comment: The final answer could be rot13(Erzbir, zvk pnssrvar, naq gnxr va -> rssnpr)?

Comment: I wondered about looking for relationships between the A,B,C words in each chain -- and then _deliberately didn't_ because I thought the language of the question ruled that out. That was stupid of me. Yes, athin and jafe, you are clearly correct. I'll edit my answer accordingly.